# Terminal Server setup for Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, terminal-server, rds, cal

I am attempting to setup a new Terminal Server, and found that MS no longer offers TS CALs. I want to verify that I will be able to achieve my desired end results with the licenses I'm currently looking at. My desired end result is the ability for 5 users to login either remotely, or in office, and have their own desktop environment when signing into the server. Similar to the old TS environment from Windows Server 2008 The current licenses I have in my shopping cart are "Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials" and "Microsoft Windows Remote Desktop Services 2012 - License 5 User CAL".

We are a very small company, and the price tag for these licenses are somewhat pricey for us, I want to ensure that they will work before pulling the trigger. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminal Services was renamed in Windows Server 2008 R2 to Remote Desktop Services. Your `Microsoft Windows Remote Desktop Services 2012 - License 5 User CAL` are the CAL's needed for your RDS users. You have 5 RDS CAL's available for use.

Answer (score 0):

Except that you will only be able to use the two built in administrator accounts concurrently. You need to either build a VM and install Windows server 2012 R2, and install your CALS on that, or buy another server to install it in.

Essentials does not support RDS internally.